# customized WPF PasswordBox does not receive mouse click event

Tags: c#, wpf

My WPF form has a customized PasswordBox and this PasswordBox seem not receive mouse click event. When i click it no Caret appears. Here is my style for PasswordBox:

```
    <Style x:Key="password" TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
        <Setter Property="Controller:PasswordBoxMonitor.IsMonitoring" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
                    <Border Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Grid>
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                            <my:QETextBlock Text="Mật khẩu" Margin="0, 0, 0, 0"  Visibility="Collapsed" FontStyle="Normal" Name="txtPrompt" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Segoe UI"  />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="Controller:PasswordBoxMonitor.PasswordLength" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="txtPrompt" Value="Visible" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="txtPrompt" Value="Hidden" />
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I try to get this control be focus by adding an event handler for mouse down event of this control:

```
    txtPassword.MouseDown += txtPassword_MouseDown;
```

my txtPassword_MouseDown function:

```
    private void txtPassword_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        txtPassword.Focus();
    }
```

But this function doesn't be excuted when i click PasswordBox.

Comment: Have you put a break point at Focus? Are you sure it isn't just the Focus() function that doesn't do what you want it to do ?

Comment: Yes, i have put a break point at txtPassword.Focus() but debugger doesn't stop at it. This PasswordBox doesn't reponse to any kind of mouse events but i does get focus when pressing tab button.

Comment: I solved it. Someone set IsHitTestVisible="False" so that it didn't response to mouse clicks. http://agsmith.wordpress.com/2008/09/16/hit-testing-in-wpf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. Someone set `IsHitTestVisible="False"` that's why it didn't response to mouse clicks.